# Nginx Rewrite rules not working for directory

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to write a below rewrite rule but somehow this is not working and I would really appreciate if someone can help me on this?

I have a Nginx reverse proxy set and my orignial server IP is 172.16.3.15 and site listens on http://172.16.3.15/web1

Hence I wrote a vhost config on Nginx server and tryin to rewrite so that that if user enters http://web1.example.local it will be diverted to http://web1.example.local/web1

server {
listen 80;
server_name web1.example.local;
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
access_log /var/log/nginx/web1/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/web1/error.log;
rewrite ^ http://web1.example.local/web1 permanent;

This is not working though; can someone please help?

TIA
Blason R